# isPrime function in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good afternoon. I need to write numbers in one line and print results also in one line. What I need to do to fix this code? At the moment code working only for one number.

```
def test_prime(n):
    if (n==1):
        return False
    elif (n==2):
        return True;
    else:
        for x in range(2,n):
            if(n % x==0):
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: Do you want to take input from user?

Comment: If it is a function dont forget the commas between arguments

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of numbers like this:

```
numbers = [3,4,5]
```

You can use `map()` to apply your `test_prime()` function to each value in the list:

```
isprime = list(map(test_prime,numbers))
```

And to print the result on one line with no commas/brackets:

```
>> print(*isprime, sep = ' ')
True False True
```

Edit: since you mentioned that you want to enter the numbers in one line with no commas, you can do:

```
>>> numbers = input().split()
1 2 3 4 5
>>> numbers
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
is_prime = lambda n: not any(n % i == 0 for i in range(2, n))
print([f'{i}: {is_prime(i)}' for i in range(1, 100)])
```

Note

- `any` is lazy, it will not iterate the whole range unless needed
- you can change the range to `range(2, n**0.5)` it you care about speed

Comment: How does this print all the results in one line?

Comment: @Barmar: the question is unclear about that, all it shows is the `is_prime` definition

Comment: It says "I need to write numbers in one line and print results also in one line." What's unclear about that?

Comment: You need to explain @blue_note

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a function `is_prime` which will call the function `test_prime` for each number in the string you input, calculates if it is prime or not, and return the resultant string.

```
def test_prime(n):
    if (n==1):
        return False
    elif (n==2):
        return True;
    else:
        for x in range(2,n):
            if(n % x==0):
                return False
        return True  

def is_prime(s):
    #Create list of numbers
    nums = [int(n) for n in s.split()]
    output = []
    #Call test_prime for each number
    for n in nums:
        output.append(test_prime(n))
    #Make a string out of results
    result = ' '.join([str(op) for op in output ])
    return result

s = input("Input numbers>>")
print(is_prime(s))
```

Here your output will be

```
Input numbers>>3 4 5
True False True
```

Comment: I need to write list off numbers without comma ( 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) in one line, and the next line is print function( True False True False True False). Two lines, first line numbers, second line print.

Comment: Write where? To a text file?

Comment: I have updated to write both in one line! please check!

Comment: What is `run module` window?

Comment: Check it please, didnt working, name 's' is not defined, and also without that s=input, programm says (    nums = [int(n) for n in s.split()]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split')

Comment: Updated, check again! Just copy the entire code as is, run it and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

To print in just a single line just use

```
for i in range(10):
    print(test_prime(i), end=' ')
```

Mind the end keyword argument for print, which defaults to '\n'. Passing some other string will prevent a newline after printing. See also here: [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

You can also generate a list and then use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which would look something like this:

```
results = [test_prime(i) for i in range(10)]
print(', '.join(results))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [print(i,test_prime(i),end=', ') for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6,10,100,1000,1013)]
1 False, 2 True, 3 True, 4 False, 5 True, 6 False, 10 False, 100 False, 1000 False, 1013 True,
```